# Spring mvc maintain session after redirect

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-mvc, session, oauth

I'm implementing a facebook login flow, where I need to save state before redirecting and retrieve it after redirecting back to app for validation purposes. I tried it like this:

```
 @RequestMapping
    public void redirectToFacebook(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        session.setAttribute("facebook_state", state);

        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(providerLoginEndpoint)
                .queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUrl)
                .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
                .queryParam("scope", "public_profile")
                .queryParam("state", state)
                .queryParam("response_type", "code");

        response.sendRedirect(uriBuilder.toUriString());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/redirect")
    public String authorize(Model model, HttpSession session,
                            @RequestParam("code") final String code,
                            final @RequestParam("state") String state) {
        String originalState = (String) session.getAttribute("facebook_state");
        //...
    }
```

Hovever `originalState` is null, and session ID is differet after callack. Is there a way to maintain the session state before and after redirect from third party host?

Answer (score 1):

Had to add this to WebSecurityConfig

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .and()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .sessionFixation().none();
    //..
```